# remote desktop connection to pc via tablet using IOS

Tags: tablet-pc

we want to develop an remote desktop application for tablet using ios.
Can any one guide us regarding about how the application realy works  and the codeing knowlegde required  !!!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what kind of application, what do you want it to do, does it need to be able to work on MacOSX as well, do you already have one for android?  are you going to make one for android?  How do you feel about a web based platform.

These are all questions you need to answer before you even think about what type of coding you are going to need/want/use.